# custom.module vs template.php

Tags: theming

This is a not-so-targeted question but I can't find any good information on this.

When is it considered correct practice to put code inside your template.php file and when to implement it in a module?

I mean in my current example I need to call hook_preprocess_node and inside perform a drupal_get_form and render that form. I've put my logic inside template.php.

Is that correct? If not, can you give me a short list of DOS and DONTS regarding the issue?

Comment: if it's too complex I put it in a module, if it's few lines of code I put it in template.php. Then it depends on the usage as well, if it's for one theme (template.php) or for different themes (module). It's up to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things I try to keep in mind when making this decision.

Is this a functional feature, or a purely visual one?  Functional components go in modules.  Purely visual ones go in the theme.

What happens if I alter or radically change the theme down the road and/or allow multiple themes for my site?  If you don't want to replicate the feature, then it should go in a module.

Drupal does make it easy to intertwine content, business logic, and presentation.  For the long term maintainability of a site, you really need to be careful when you implement things.

A good rule of thumb is that a theme should not need to know about IDs (`$nid`, `$uid`, `$tid`, etc) for anything, and should only need to know machine names to alter visual appearance.

In your case, adding a form to a node is a functional change, and I would really put that in a module.